# Copy Adjacent Cells if Column Matches the Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have this data:

[image]

and i am trying to copy the adjacent cells if Col"B" has this value "Yer" but my code is incomplete and i am struggling to copy paste the adjacent cell.

any help will be appreciated.

Result will be like this:

[image]

```
 Sub MyTry()
    
        Dim myDataRng As Range
        Dim cell As Range
    
        Set myDataRng = Range("C2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
        
        For Each cell In myDataRng
            If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Yer") > 0 Then
    
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 3) = cell.Value
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 2).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value 
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 4).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 4).Value 
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 5).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 5).Value
    
            End If
        Next cell
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you trying to copy to?  Seems like you will get multiple matches so how are they handled?

Comment: I did not added them in code because it was giving an error. '    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 12).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 4).Value
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 13).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 5).Value'

Comment: When adding code please edit your question and add it there - code in comments is too difficult to read if it's more than one line...

Comment: Updated the code in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim myDataRng As Range
    Dim cell As Range, wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim destRow As Range
    
    Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")  'source sheet
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'destination sheet
    
    Set myDataRng = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set destRow = wsDest.Rows(2)  'first destination row
    For Each cell In myDataRng
        If InStr(1, cell.Value, "Yer") > 0 Then
            With cell.EntireRow 'the whole matching row
                destRow.Cells(3).Value = cell.Value
                destRow.Cells(2).Value = .Cells(2).Value
                destRow.Cells(4).Value = .Cells(4).Value
                destRow.Cells(5).Value = .Cells(5).Value
            End With
            Set destRow = destRow.Offset(1, 0) 'next destination row
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Its amazing! you are genius Thank you. @Tim Williams